# Sobrescrever CSS componente calendar Primefaces

Tags: css, primefaces

Estou utilizando o componente `calendar` do `Primefaces`, porém estou com dificuldade para sobrescrever o `CSS` do mesmo.
Segue meu código no `xhtml`:

```
<h:panelGrid columns="2" columnClasses="col one, col one">
                <h:outputLabel value="Data Início:"
                    styleClass="label" style="width: 50% !important" />
                <h:outputLabel value="Data Fim:"
                    styleClass="label" style="width: 50% !important" />

                <p:calendar pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" mode="popup" required="true"
                            showOn="button" popupIconOnly="true"
                            value="#{bean.entidade.dataIni}" locale="pt_BR"
                            showButtonPanel="false" readonlyInput="true"
                            maxlength="10" />

                <p:calendar pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" mode="popup" required="true"
                            showOn="button" popupIconOnly="true"
                            value="#{bean.entidade.dataFim}" locale="pt_BR"
                            showButtonPanel="false" readonlyInput="true"
                            maxlength="10" />
            </h:panelGrid>
```

Meu problema está em que estou setando um estilo `style="width: 50% !important"` que não é aplicado, e os dois componentes `calendar` ficam um abaixo do outro.

Obs: o `CSS` col one é p seguinte:

```
.col.one,.col.one * {
    width: 900px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontrei a solução para esse caso alterando o meu `panelGrid` para este:

```
<h:panelGrid columns="2" width="100%" columnClasses="col two manuaisPratica,col two" >
```

onde o `col one` e `col two` é facil de alterar/sobrescrever pelo style dos componentes internos, o problema estava no `CSS` padrão

```
.col.two:FIRST-CHILD {
    padding-right: 20px;
}
.col.two * {
    /*width: 440px;*/
    width: 348px;
}
```

e que acabei tendo que customizar a primeira coluna(pois estava quebrando o leiaute) dessa forma:

```
.col.two.manuaisPratica
{
    width:50% !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

O componente calendar tem o atributo size, la você pode alterar o tamanho do input que é gerado pelo componente. 
Exemplo:

`<p:calendar pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" mode="popup" required="true" showOn="button" popupIconOnly="true" value="#{bean.entidade.dataIni}" locale="pt_BR" showButtonPanel="false" readonlyInput="true" maxlength="10" size="30"/>`

Comment: Como? Poderia dar exemplos?

Comment: Obrigado pelo exemplo, porém eu já utilizava ambos e não havia resolvido no meu caso.

Answer (score 0):

Para deixá-los lado a lado, você pode usar *floats*:

```
style="width: 50% !important; float:left !important"
```

Comment: Opa, tentei utilizar isso antes mesmo de postar a dúvida, porém não resolveu.